# How to fix incorrect highlighting from 'matchpairs' caused by setline()

Tags: vimscript

when using `setline()` to insert brackets, `matchpairs` does not do its job correctly. Using these commands

```
fu Test()
    cal setline(".", "()")
endf

au TextChangedI * cal Test()
```

set up the text

```
(

)
```

upon typing `(` into the middle line, (with `matchpairs` including `(:)`) you will get

```
(
|(|)
|)|
```

(`||` represents what's highlighted)

I've tried disabling and reinstating `matchpairs` but I couldn't get that to work. How can I make it behave as it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`'matchpairs'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27matchpairs%27) option itself doesn't perform any highlighting. It's the [standard plugin](http://www.vimhelp.org/usr_05.txt.html#standard-plugin) [`matchparen`](https://www.vimhelp.org/pi_paren.txt.html) that actually does the highlighting.

The problem is that the autocommands `matchparen` uses to implement the highlighting don't line up well with your code*. For a quick fix, try disabling the highlighting before making your change, and reinstating it afterwards:

```
function! Test()
    NoMatchParen
    call setline(".", "()")
    DoMatchParen
endfunction
```

<sub>* Specifically, what's happening is that you are entering the `(`, the matchparen autocommand fires and highlights the last `)`, *then* your autocommand fires and changes the text (but not the highlighting). Then, (at least in my configuration) after a pause, another matchparen autocommand will fire and update the highlighting to be correct.</sub>

Comment: Turns out just a `DoMatchParen` afterwards is enough to fix it!